# Impala JDBC Error: User '' does not have privileges to execute 'SELECT' on: table

Tags: java, jdbc, hive, impala

Resently I enabled the Sentry policy file for Hive. So when I try to execute a query in Impala using Impala-JDBC4 (version 2.5.16) I get this error:

```
errorMessage:AuthorizationException: User '' does not have privileges to execute 'SELECT' on: db.table
```

In my code I set the user and password of my admin account of my DB. So I don't undestand why it don't reads that.

```
public static double getDolarFromImpala(String date)  {
    double dolar = 0.0;
    try {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER_IMPALA);
        String sql = "SELECT value FROM db.table where date ='"+date+"'";
        String JDBC_IMPALA_URL = "jdbc:impala://impala1:21050;auth=noSasl;UseNativeQuery=1";

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_IMPALA_URL,IMPALA_USER,IMPALA_PASSWORD);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next()){
            dolar = rs.getDouble("value");                                          
        }
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException se){
          //Handle errors for JDBC
          se.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
          //Handle errors for Class.forName
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dolar;
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because the user you are using to run the code does not have privileges to the database you are using in the impala. To enable this follow the below commands.

NOTE: ALL THESE COMMANDS SHOULD BE EXECUTED FROM THE IMPALA SUPER USER

First you have to create a role to your job `CREATE ROLE role_name;`
Next you have to grant that particular role to the user you are using `GRANT ROLE role_name TO GROUP user_name` (I used functional user, you can name user instead of group too)
Final step is granting the permissions to the database for that particular role `GRANT ALL ON database database_name TO ROLE role_name;`

After this steps try running the code from the user which you granted the role.

for more information go through this link: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/sg_hive_sql.html

Comment: That doesn't work if the policy file is active in Impala. I already have a  user (`IMPALA_USER`) and password (`IMPALA_PASSWORD`) that has privileges to execute that query. The thing is when I write the `IMPALA_USER` the error doesn't show `User 'IMPALA_USER' does not have privileges`, instead the user is empty. Is like the JDBC doesn't run the query using the user that I set.

Comment: Have you tried passing the username and password along with the correct authentication mechanism in the JDBC connection string as described in the Cloudera Impala JDBC driver installation PDF document which is bundled with the JDBC driver? Try something like this:  `jdbc:impala://impala1:21050;AuthMech=3;UID=IMPALA_USER;PWD=IMPALA_PASSWORD;UseSasl=0;UseNativeQuery=1`

Comment: Used that connection URL

Comment: Used that connection URL and the program got stuck in the `DriverManager.getConnection`. This is a the last trace of the Driver logs didn't saw any error:
`dic 26 12:31:17.762 TRACE 1 com.cloudera.impala.hivecommon.core.HiveJDBCEnvironment.createConnection(): +++++ enter +++
++`

Comment: @JoaquínSilva Were you able to get past this step? I am stuck here and would appreciate any input. Thanks!

Comment: Here is a solution to the same issue: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/4240